# Is there a categorification of "(virtually) solvable"?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, normal-subgroups, solvable-groups, categorification

*If this question doesn't make sense or is otherwise poor quality, then I'm sorry.*

### Motivation:

As part of my research, I study [virtually solvable (1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group) groups. These are goups that have a solvable subgroup of finite index.

I am interested in looking at this group theoretic property from a wider perspective to see if I can get inspiration for proving various things about virtually solvable groups.

### The Question:

> What would be a categorification of the property of being (virtually) solvable for groups?

### Thoughts:

I think that if I have a categorification of solvable, then a categorification of virtually solvable would follow by using things like subobjects. Whether or not I could form such a definition would depend on the nature of the first categorification.

A good place to start might be [group extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension), which, as far as I understand, are categorical; they're essentially [short exact sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence#Short_exact_sequence). In fact, I think the latter (with a few bells & whistles) are pretty much a categorification of "solvable" anyway but I'm not sure. My understanding of these is minimal though. I would appreciate help with them.

### Some Extra Context:

I'm completely self-taught when it comes to category theory. However, I have asked some questions of modest difficulty about category theory here on MSE in the past and the answers seem to make sense to me.

Please help :)

---

(1) See the "Related Concepts" section of the article linked to.

Comment: Do you mean whether it is possible to describe being virtually solvable "inside" the category of groups? Because the answer to that is yes.

Comment: If that's the extent of what can be done, then yes, of course, but what I'm hoping for is maybe something that resembles virtual solvability in general for other categories, yet specialises to virtual solvability of groups in the category of groups, @TobiasKildetoft.

Comment: Well, we could write up what it means in the category of groups and then use that as a definition in other categories, but it might not be the "best", since we might have made some choices along the way between various equivalent ways of defining things which are not equivalent in other categories (for example, we can recognize abelian groups as the group objects, but these seem like an odd choice in general for the type of objects with which to build solvable objects).

Comment: This is not what "categorification" means, really.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Agreed, but I could not think of anything else in this particular case, since what was being categorified was a property rather than an object.

Comment: Is there a "categorification" of other classes of groups that fit what you are looking for in virtually solvable groups?(like the much tamer classes of groups virtually nilpotent, or abelian etc)

Comment: I don't know, @PaulPlummer. I'll have a look over the next few days then report back :)

Comment: @PaulPlummer, I haven't found anything yet, although, to be honest, I haven't looked all that much - I've been somewhat busy.

Comment: No problem. Have you looked at abelian categories? Although I don't really think that is what you are looking for, based on your question. It is worth noting, in some aspects, solvable groups are badly behaved. For example some have unsolvable word problem, or have abelian subgroups of countably infinite rank(maybe these things do not pose a problem to what you are trying to do though).